# Change values of blocks of cells in column separated by empty cells

Tags: excel, vba, row

I have a column of data with blocks of non-empty cells followed by blocks of empty cells. See picture below. I'm trying to develop a macro that inserts formulas within each block of non-empty cells and ends when it reaches the last non-empty cell block in the column. What I cannot figure out is how to generalize finding the first and last cell in each non-empty cell block. Perhaps there is some counting method such as `firstrow(i)` and `lastrow(i)` Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Data layout:

[image]

Macro:

```
Sub test()

Dim r As Integer
Dim firstrowX, lastrowX  As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")

With sht

'first row in block
firstrowX = sht.Cells(3, 12).End(xlDown).Row
'last row in block
lastrowX = sht.Cells(firstrowX, 12).End(xlDown).Row
'last row in column
lastrowCol = sht.Cells(Rows.count, 12).End(xlUp).Row

    For r = firstrowX To lastrowX

        If r <> lastrowX Then
        .Cells(r, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=RC[-6],1, IF(R" & lastrowX & "C[]=1, -1, 0))"
        Else
        .Cells(r, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=RC[-6],1,0)"
        End If
        If lastrowX = lastrowCol Then
        Exit Sub

    Next r

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you're looping through all cells in that column anyway, you could just use an If block:

```
For r = firstrowX To lastrowX
If Cells(r, 12).Value <> vbNullString Then
        If r <> lastrowX Then
        .Cells(r, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=RC[-6],1, IF(R" & lastrowX & "C[]=1, -1, 0))"
        Else
        .Cells(r, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=RC[-6],1,0)"
        End If
        If lastrowX = lastrowCol Then
        Exit Sub
End If

Next r
```

---

But the easier method would be to use `SpecialCells()`

Assuming your cells contain constant data as your image suggests:

```
For Each cell In .Range("L2:L" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = vbNullString Then
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=RC[-6],1,0)"
    Else
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=RC[-6],1, IF(R" & cell.End(xlDown).Row & "C[]=1, -1, 0))"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks @MacroMan! The only thing is that lastrowX should apply to the last cell in each cell block. Not to the last cell in the entire column.

Comment: If you use `SpecialCells()` though you don't need `lastrowX` because you are only looping through cells that have a value - the loop will automatically jump between each block.

Comment: OK thanks! There is another issue: the last cell of each non-empty cell block must have this formula: `.Cells(r, 12).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=RC[-6],1,0)"`

Comment: Sorry, I get what you mean about `lastRowX` now, I've updated my edit as you don't need that variable anymore

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx). If the cells already contain formulas returning numbers, you can target that subset specifically with the [xlCellType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx)

```
Dim lastrowX As Long
With Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(12)
    lastrowX = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=RC[-6],1, IF(R" & lastrowX & "C[]=1, -1, 0))"
    End With
    .Cells(lastrowX, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=RC[-6],1,0)"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped! The only thing is that `lastrowX` should apply to the last cell in each cell block. Not to the last cell in the column.

Answer (score 0):

This one isn't as compact as the others, but it's written similar to yours. You can step through it to see how the formula works:

```
Sub example()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).row
    'lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
End With

Dim Column2Copy As String
Column2Copy = "L"

Dim startCell As Range
Set startCell = Cells(3, 12).End(xlDown)


Do While startCell.row < lastRow
    If startCell.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).row > lastRow Then
        newLastRow = lastRow
    Else
        newLastRow = startCell.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).row
    End If

    If newLastRow > lastRow Then
        Range(Cells(startCell.row, Column2Copy), Cells(newLastRow, Column2Copy)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=RC[-6],1, IF(R" & lastRow & "C[]=1, -1, 0))"
    Else
        Range(Cells(startCell.row, Column2Copy), Cells(newLastRow, Column2Copy)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=RC[-6],1,0)"
    End If

    Set startCell = startCell.End(xlDown)

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```